# How to prevent drupal select 10 articles on front page by default?

Tags: theming

The thing is I don't know where to disable this action, even after I rebuild my frontpage with other blocks/views/panels instead the default blog list style page, drupal will still do the select from database. At /config/system/site-information can change number of articles drupal select, but cannot really turn it off.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the duplicate is what you're asking, if not please let me know and we'll clear it up and get this re-opened

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the similar question. but maybe I find the answer, use hook_menu_alter(), overriding node menu's callback..?